# Azure Purview - Scan file types

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-purview

We are scanning an Azure Data Lake (Gen 2). In the scan results we get some files that we don't want to appear in the asset register - for example, a configuration file (.wmk) as per the below. If there any way to hide all files of a certain type? I looked at the scanning rules to see if a custom rule would work and the file type (.wmk) is not listed as a scan target however it does appear in the asset register.

Similar applies to data lake folders, we would only like to see resource sets and not the folders in the assets.

Is there a way to keep them from showing in the assets?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before scanning you can **scope** your scan to specific folders or subfolders by choosing the appropriate items in the list. Once the data source is registered and scanned, the Data map extracts information about the structure (hierarchical namespace) of the data source. This information is used to build the browsing experience for data discovery.

[image]

> Note:
>
> - All future assets under a certain parent will be automatically selected if the parent is fully or partially checked
> - After a successful scan, there may be delay before newly scanned assets appear in the browse experience. This delay may take up to a
>   few hours.

While searching the catalog for assets, **operators** can be **used to compose a search query.**

Specifically you can use the Boolean operators **NOT** in all caps to specify what an asset can't contain as a keyword to the right of the clause or use **'*'** a wildcard that matches on one to many characters so that your query does not return assets that have properties with (.wmk) in them.

```
Example: Expense NOT wmk NOT *.wmk
```

(Operators can be combined as many times as need in a single query.)

**Concept of resource sets:**

- A resource set is a single object in the catalog that represents a
  large number of assets in storage.
- To address the challenge of mapping large numbers of data assets to a
  single logical resource, Azure Purview uses resource sets.
- Azure Purview automatically detects resource sets when scanning. This
  feature looks at all of the data that's ingested via scanning and
  compares it to a set of **defined patterns**. Then it switches from a
  full scan to a sample scan.
- In a sample scan, **it opens only a subset of the files that it thinks
  are in the resource set**. For each file it does open, it uses its
  schema and runs its classifiers.
- Azure Purview then finds **the newest resource among the opened
  resources and uses that resource's schema and classifications in the
  entry for the entire resource set in the catalog.** Stores aggregate
  information about the partition resources that make up the resource
  set.

To **customize or override** how Azure Purview detects which assets are grouped as resource sets and how they are displayed within the catalog, **you can define pattern** rules in the management center.

**Create resource set pattern rules:**

1. Go to the management center. Select Pattern rules from the menu
   under the Resource sets heading. Select + New to create a new rule
   set.

[image]

2. Enter the scope of your resource set pattern rule. (Folder path)
3. Update the fields appropriately, in your case mainly, **Qualified
   name** and **Do not group as resource set**

[image]

> Note: After a pattern rule is created, all new scans will apply the
> rule during ingestion. Existing assets in the data catalog will be
> updated via a background process which can take up to a few hours.

**E*xample: Don't group .wmk files into resource set*s**

**Input Files:**

```
https://myazureblob.blob.core.windows.net/bar/raw/Expense-7/01-01-2020/22:33:22-001.xls
https://myazureblob.blob.core.windows.net/bar/raw/Expense-8/01-01-2020/22:33:22-002.wmk
```

**Pattern rule**

```
Scope: https://myazureblob.blob.core.windows.net/bar/

Display name: Expense-{{Fileid}}

Qualified Name: raw/Filename-{{Fileid:int}}/{{:date}}/{{:time}}-{{:int}}.wmk

Resource Set: false
```

**Output individual assets**

```
Asset 1

Display name: Expense-7

Qualified Name: https://myazureblob.blob.core.windows.net/bar/raw/Expense-7/01-01-2020/22:33:22-001.xls
```

Additionally, if you feel this is not helpful, you can share your [Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/932437-azure-purview) so the product team can look into this idea. ✌

Comment: Great answer - very helpful, thanks Batman!

Comment: The dawn is coming ‍♂️